# Makefile compile a library in another directory when it doesn't exist or the directory has been modify

Tags: makefile, directory, shared-libraries

Hi i have a makefile that compiles my library and then compiles the program. What i want to do is that the makefile recompile alway i modify my library's files for that i thought in this

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(PATH_LIB.A)","")
FILE_EXIST = 1
else
FILE_EXIST = 0
endif

$(MAIN_PROCESS): $(PATH_LIB.A) check_lib
...thing to do...

$(PATH_LIB.a):
FILE_EXIST = 0

check_lib:
ifeq("$(FILE_EXIST)","0")
    $(MAKE) -C $(PATH_MAKEFILE_LIB.A)
endif
```

My problem es that when i compile it relinks all time "...thins to do..." because is checking all time check_lib as updateable what do you suggest for do what i want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is not a scripting language like bash or python. What it needs is a description of inter-dependencies between targets and prerequisites, plus recipes to build them. In your case (but I am not sure I understood all details) you could try:

```
$(MAIN_PROCESS): $(PATH_LIB.A)
    ...thing to do...

$(PATH_LIB.A):
    $(MAKE) -C $(PATH_MAKEFILE_LIB.A)
```

And that's all (but continue reading, there is more to understand). This tells make that:

1. `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` depends on `$(PATH_LIB.A)`, plus the things to do to build `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` if it does not exist or if it is older than `$(PATH_LIB.A)`.
2. `$(PATH_LIB.A)` depends on nothing, plus what to do if it does not exist.

It almost works. Almost only because if `$(PATH_LIB.A)` already exists but is out of date (with respect to its own source files) it will not be rebuilt. A solution is to declare it as *phony*:

```
.PHONY: $(PATH_LIB.A)

$(MAIN_PROCESS): $(PATH_LIB.A)
    ...thing to do...

$(PATH_LIB.A):
    $(MAKE) -C $(PATH_MAKEFILE_LIB.A)
```

This way make will always try to rebuild it, even if it already exists. The sub-make will do it if needed, else it will just tell you that it was up to date. But it is not the whole story: as make always tries to rebuild `$(PATH_LIB.A)`, it will consider that `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` must also be rebuilt, even if the sub-make didn't do anything because `$(PATH_LIB.A)` was up-to-date.

If this is a problem, more tricky solutions can be used, like using one more sub-make. The idea is the following:

1. Use make conditionals to create two different contexts of invocation with two different rules for your `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` target.
2. On the first invocation of make, the first context is used where `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` depends on the **phony** `$(PATH_LIB.A)` but its recipe, instead of `...thing to do...` is a second invocation of make, in the other context.
3. For this second invocation `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` depends on the **non-phony** `$(PATH_LIB.A)` and will have its normal recipe.

The two contexts are distinguished thanks to a dedicated make variable (`SECONDPASS` in the code below).

Example:

```
host> cat lib/Makefile
foo.a: foo.c
    touch $@

host> cat Makefile
ifeq ($(SECONDPASS),)
$(MAIN_PROCESS): $(PATH_LIB.A)
    $(MAKE) SECONDPASS=1

.PHONY: $(PATH_LIB.A)

$(PATH_LIB.A):
    $(MAKE) -C $(dir $@)
else
$(MAIN_PROCESS): $(PATH_LIB.A)
    touch $@
endif

host> make --no-print-directory
make -C lib/
touch foo.a
make SECONDPASS=1
touch bar

host> make --no-print-directory
make[1]: 'foo.a' is up to date.
make SECONDPASS=1
make[1]: 'bar' is up to date.

host> touch lib/foo.c

host> make --no-print-directory
make -C lib/
touch foo.a
make SECONDPASS=1
touch bar

host> touch lib/foo.a

host> make --no-print-directory
make -C lib/
make[1]: 'foo.a' is up to date.
make SECONDPASS=1
touch bar
```

Comment: Mmmm i understand what you are saying but for example if my `lib.a` has a file called `foo.c` and i modify `foo.c` (inside lib.a's directory) when i'll do make it will check `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` with `$(PATH_LIB.A)` and they will match despite that `lib.a` **should be updated**.

Maybe i should check all files in the lib's directory? but in that case am i forced to create another macro with every function my lib use?

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez: No, as it is phony, make will always try to rebuild `$(PATH_LIB.A)`. And to do this, it will launch the sub-make that takes care of the source files of `$(PATH_LIB.A)`. Note that I forgot to mention a drawback of this approach: `$(MAIN_PROCESS)` will also always be rebuilt, even if the sub-make finally decided that `$(PATH_LIB.A)` was up-to-date. Is this a problem?

Comment: Oh looks like the `.PHONY` thing was enought but until now i have been using `.PHONY` at the very top of the Makefile and like that didn't work properly and when i saw your example i tried to write the `.PHONY: $(PATH_LIB.A)` just before the rule and that works. Now im realising that i said to Makefile to phony $(PATH_LIB.A) before declaring it and probably that was cause it didn't work. Thank you so much.

Comment: I used the tricky part to solve the problem in the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51110668/10010027 if you post it i will tick as correct. Thank you!