# Makefile execute echo only one time inside a rule

Tags: if-statement, makefile, rules

I have this Makefile

```
$(MAIN) : $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS) : %.c
     compile file
```

And i want to use `printf` for print something like "compiling" whenever a file needs compile and "done" if a file has been compiled at the end of every compiled for example:

```
Compiling
file1.c
file2.c
file3.c
Done
```

I have tried to use sentences like `if` from shell or `ifeq` from makefile
but i need a variable and makefile doesn't let me change the value of a variable inside of a if i don't know why. How can i archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem making a variable `MODE` initialized to 0 and dividing my makefile in two parts one part check if something has been modified where in that case instead o update the fails i print my messages and then do `$(MAKE) MODE=1` where i perform a normal makefile that update everything needed

Thanks to Renauld Pacalet in the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51100086/10010027

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
 OBJECTS := file1.o file2.o file3.o

.PHONY: all compiling

all : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Done

compiling:
    @echo Compiling

$(OBJECTS): file%.o : file%.c compiling
    @echo $<
    @compile $<
```

Comment: mmmm it works more or less because for explain my problem i said to much little information. My real case is that im not compiling objects im creating a library then i use `.PHONY` with a rule that creates my library for check every time i do make if any source from the library has been modified then what i want is that the messages "Compiling" and "Done" only appears when the library is being compiling (or updating) and not when the library is already updated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need to print a message when starting building a bunch of PDF files, and then jump to generate another bunch of PNG files. I used two .INTERMEDIATE target to prevent `make` of being "hungry" (expecting the update) of a .PHONY target file.

The message will print only once.

```
 CC=gcc
 OBJECTS := file1.o file2.o file3.o

.PHONY: all 
 all:  $(OBJECTS) msg_compiling

$(OBJECTS): file%.o : file%.c msg_compiling
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< 

.INTERMEDIATE: msg_compiling
 msg_compiling:
    @printf "\n Compiling \n"
```

This is explained in the GNU make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html